# How do I manually perform a password check using AIXpert?

Tags: password, root, aix

One of the AIXpert tools is to perform a check of the root password against a dictionary (usually /etc/security/aixpert/dictionary/English). If I want to run this check manually, how would I do it?

I've had a look through some config files and I think the /etc/security/aixpert/bin/chuserstanza is involved, but everytime I use it (with various args) it just exits and returns 0.